# Exclude 1 Year from a date range

Tags: sql, databricks

I would like to exclude the year 2020 from my column the_date_transaction which is a timestamp.
I have written this but it returns 'Query returned no results':

**WHERE
to_date(tdt.the_date_transaction) BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-31'
AND to_date(tdt.the_date_transaction) BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2022-11-31'**

I have searched on stackoverflow but no luck, can someone please help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `NOT BETWEEN` instead:

```sql
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE to_date(tdt.the_date_transaction) NOT BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-12-31'
```